# How to log all Redis commands executed in a Python script?

Tags: python, redis

I have a Python script that executes Redis commands via [`redis-py`](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py). How can I print the commands being executed when the script runs for debugging purposes? I have access to both the code and the Redis server.

Comment: Add decorators that call `logging` https://pymotw.com/3/logging/index.html to the Redis calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Monitor](https://redis.io/commands/monitor) command.

All you have to do is open the `redis-cli` and call `MONITOR`, and then it will log every command sent to Redis.

```sh
$ redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> MONITOR
OK
1617778908.016538 [0 127.0.0.1:38138] "set" "foo" "bar"
```

Comment: Great solution! Might be worth adding that you don't actually need to *"enter"* the CLI, you can start monitoring from outside if you want to redirect the output to a file or process it with `awk` or similar, e.g. `redis-cli MONITOR | awk '...'` or like `redis-cli MONITOR > redis.log`